# Create a Button to input text, Save and Copy to paste on another platform

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working as a chat support guy with knowledge in HTML5 / CSS3 and a bit of JS. 
I'd like a code where in I can input one script on an individual button.
For example, 'How can I help you?' or 'Thank you for contacting us'
That button stores and copies the script so I can paste it as a reply when I click on it.
This way, I can choose from multiple buttons easily depending on the category of inquiry.
I can save time typing long responses from silly repetitive questions.

Here's an example of what I did,

```
<td colspan="1"><div id = "chat">
<button onclick="copy('Are you still there?')">Still there?</button>
<button onclick="copy('One moment please')">1moment</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this either, but per [Hacker Noon](https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f)

Your copy function would look like this. The exceCommand('copy') function copies the "selection" from the HTML document. So, first we create a spoof textarea element with the string you want copied inside of it. Then, we execute the command to copy the selected string to the clipboard. After, the spoof element is destroyed. This function also adds CSS attributes to make sure the user visual isn't impacted.

```
  const copy = str => {
      const el = document.createElement('textarea');  // Create a <textarea> element
      el.value = str;                                 // Set its value to the string that you want copied
      el.setAttribute('readonly', '');                // Make it readonly to be tamper-proof
      el.style.position = 'absolute';                 
      el.style.left = '-9999px';                      // Move outside the screen to make it invisible
      document.body.appendChild(el);                  // Append the <textarea> element to the HTML document
      const selected =            
        document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0        // Check if there is any content selected previously
          ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)     // Store selection if found
          : false;                                    // Mark as false to know no selection existed before
      el.select();                                    // Select the <textarea> content
      document.execCommand('copy');                   // Copy - only works as a result of a user action (e.g. click events)
      document.body.removeChild(el);                  // Remove the <textarea> element
      if (selected) {                                 // If a selection existed before copying
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();    // Unselect everything on the HTML document
        document.getSelection().addRange(selected);   // Restore the original selection
      }
    };
```